# Firebase Google cloud Function - Database Trigger - How to delete extra records & files programmatically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Use case:**

Users can upload images using UI (mobile, web). Firebase storage and insertion of database record for the file is done in UI. Users can upload a set number of files say for testing max 5. Solution is achieved through Firebase Storage to store files and Firebase Database to track the URLs of the image for future use in other screens.

I have a google cloud function that gets triggered when a user uploads an image in frontend to firebase storage. Once the file is uploaded I create a firebase database record under the uid. the google cloud function triggers `onCreate()`.

Structure of Database

```
Users/{uid}/images/
{ name: file1.jpg, date_created: "2017-11-01", downloadURL : "//...."}
```

For every record creation I check the count of records under `uid/images` node and check if the snapshot is greater than `MAX_LIMIT`. If it is greater than `MAX_LIMIT` I attempt to remove the record from the database and in another GCF (listening to `.onDelete()` Trigger) I delete the firebase storage file.

The issue is Once the record count gets more than `MAX_LIMIT`... the snapshot behaves strange. It iteratively deletes all the records thus triggering GCF Delete function and removing all files from storage.

No issues with GCF delete function for storage.. it works charm... and removes all files from storage due to the code behavior in GCF onCreate DB function.

To keep short putting below just the function that is logic trouble.

```
//var database = admin.database(); passed to function
exports.handler = function(event, database, esClient)
{
  var usersRef = database.ref('users');
  console.log('inside Backend Function1 - 
  checkImageCounterFunction');
  console.log( 'event data =' + JSON.stringify(event.data.val()) );
  console.log('event data length =' + event.data.numChildren());
  console.log('event.params.uid =' + event.params.uid );

  var objLength = 0;
  usersRef.child(event.params.uid+'/images').once('value', 
  function(snapshot) {
      console.log('Count: ' + snapshot.numChildren());
      objLength = snapshot.numChildren();
      console.log('database ref length =' + objLength);
     if(objLength > 0) {
        if(objLength > serverConfig.max_image_counter){
          console.log('Maximum number of images upload found. 
          Deleting old images and records.');
          var readDBPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
          {
           usersRef.child(event.params.uid+'/images')
           .orderByChild('date_created')
           .limitToFirst(objLength - serverConfig.max_image_counter)
           .on("value", function(snapshot) {
                console.log('snapshot.val() 
                      =>'+JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()) );
             snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
                     console.log('snapshot.for.data value 
                       ='+JSON.stringify(data) );
              console.log('item Key = ' + data.key + ' val ='+ 
              JSON.stringify(data.val()));
          usersRef.child(event.params.uid+'/images/'+data.key)
           .remove(function (error) {
              if (!error)
                  console.log('Success - Firebase Database remove 
                     {'+data.val().name+'}');
              else
                  console.log('Error - Firebase Database remove 
                     {'+data.val().name+'}');
              });
          });
          resolve();
        });
      });
      readDBPromise.then(function (result){
        console.log('Returning from function!');
        usersRef.child(event.params.uid+'/image_counter')
        .set(serverConfig.max_image_counter);
        return;
      });
    } //end if objLength > MAX
    else
      return usersRef.child(event.params.uid+'/image_counter')
              .set(objLength);
    }
    else
      console.log('objLength is 0 or negative = '+objLength);
      return;
    });
  //return;
 };
```

Comment: Logs - if any additional info required - 8:02:40.559 AM

Success - Firebase Database remove {DashLanding1.jpg}
8:02:40.358 AM

Success - Firebase Database remove {championship-profit-loss-2009-11.jpg}
8:02:39.958 AM
info 
checkImageCounterFunction
Success - Firebase Database remove {CashFlow.png}
8:02:39.358 AM

Success - Firebase Database remove {BalanceSheet Report.png}
8:02:39.958 AM

Success - Firebase Database remove {CashFlow.png}

Comment: I'm wondering about the use of `on()` to attach a listener in this line: `.on("value", function(snapshot) {`.  Isn't `once()` what you need?  It looks like later in the code you `remove()` sub-values from the location, which will cause the listener to fire multiple times.

Comment: Yes you rigtht! thanks for the oversight. I totally missed that I am using .on() rather than .once(). Also, I am changing the logic as snapshot.forEach() gets called multiple times. Not sure why but I also noticed that my logic is redundant. As soon as the file number reaches MAX_LIMIT + 1 there will be an attempt to remove oldest file in database/storage. So, snapshot will always be just one record from DB. No need to perform forEach() loop.

Comment: One more issue found... I am watching google cloud logs and not sure if they are in realtime but google cloud function finishes and prints console.log last statement but the file remove success comes on google console.logs later. Not sure if it is an issue

Comment: The query, set, and remove operations you are performing are asynchronous and return a Promise.  You need to chain them together and return a Promise as [the result of the Cloud Function trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  It doesn't appear you are doing that.

Comment: Any reference or help on how to do it will be very much appreciated. I am trying to get my head around on how best to achieve it in my function context.

Comment: The video at the link in my previous comment is helpful.  I can't offer more help than that.  Chaining Promises is tricky when there are multiple asynch calls.

Comment: Thanks... I will go through the video in next couple of days and try to improve the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Bob Snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4815718/bob-snyder)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422580/firebase-google-cloud-function-database-trigger-how-to-delete-extra-records/48873916#comment81805321_47422580)

> The query, set, and remove operations you are performing are asynchronous and return a Promise. You need to chain them together and return a Promise as [the result of the Cloud Function trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). It doesn't appear you are doing that